# Why can't I do strcpy?

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
   const char* hello = "Hello, World!";
   char *str = malloc(14 * sizeof(char));

   for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
      strcpy(str[i],hello[i]);
   }
   str[14]='\0';

   printf("%s\n", str);

   return 0;
}
```

Compilation warnings:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]   
note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char'   
warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

str is a pointer and hello too, what's going on?

Comment: Neither `str[i]` nor `hello[i]` is a pointer -- both are characters. And the next problem is that `str[14]` is off the end of the allocated memory -- you've allocated 14 bytes, with valid indexes from 0 to 13.

Comment: `str` is a pointer, `str[i]` is not.

Comment: `strcpy(str, hello)` is the correct invocation.

Comment: ... *without the loop*.

Comment: I forget that strcpy copies the null character, thanks

Comment: `char *str = strdup(hello);` copies the string without needing to worry about counting bytes.

Comment: @PaulHankin `strdup` is not standard.

Comment: @MichaelWalz it's in the POSIX standard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it wrong:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
   const char* hello = "Hello, World!";
   char *str = malloc(strlen(hello)+1);

   strcpy(str,hello);
   printf("%s\n", str);
   free(str);
   return 0;
}
```

Explanation:
`strcpy` operates on pointers, where both are start location to write to and read from, so you have to pass those, not characters. Your read location is `hello`, your write location is `str`. Then `strcpy` loops until it finds a `0` character (which is included) to stop copying, so your loop is unnecessary. Last thing is that you have to free allocated memory. Also `sizeof(char)` doesn't make sense: it's always 1.

Comment: You present a correct implementation, but this would be a much better answer if it also *explained* why the OP's code is wrong, and what the error messages mean.

Comment: Agree just added that, maybe that will help understand the problem

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is your attempting to use C-strings as arrays of characters, which is certainly allowed but it's a different behavior than using them as *pointers* to *null-terminated* strings. Doing `hello[0]` evaluates to the first character of the string, which is simply a usually 8-bit integer. A `char` is a value, it does not correspond to a memory address.
The correct statement you want is

```
strcpy(str, hello);
```

For reference, if you want to get a string starting at some point in your string, you would do

```
strcpy(str, hello + 1);
```

Performing addition on a pointer evaluates to a pointer that is some n addresses forward in memory.

Comment: You might want to delete references to pointer arithmetic - it's probably off-topic in this answer, and may be generally confusing.

Comment: deleted it, but i thought the asker was attempting to get the ith point where a string starts by mistakenly doing str[i] in a function that accepts a pointer.

Comment: `hello[0]` evaluates a `char` which is usually 8-bit (but may not be) and can be signed or unsigned. Only some `char`s are printable characters (specifically the non-negative ones for which `isprint(c)` returns non-zero). I think your answer is in spirit correct, but these small technical errors subtract from its quality.

Comment: @PaulHankin good point, I fixed it just to clarify that a char is a value and not an address of memory or a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `strcpy` takes two `char` pointers not the `str[]`, `hello[]`  arrays.

```
char *strcpy(char *destination, const char *source)
```